# ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit inbound only?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

quick question: ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = x in Azure Worker role, is that inbound only? Or outbound too?

Also - is it per ROLE or per INSTANCE. So if I have 4 instances - do I have a limit of x for all the instances, or x per instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's per instance - we tested and verified it.

Comment: You haven't answered the inbound / outbound bit so I will - it's outbound.

Comment: Correct - sorry for that.